# Hacer un sort a un Object (JS)

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

Tengo un Object con la siguiente estructura:

```
[
  {
    titulo: '',
    id: '',
    imagen: '',
    fecha: ''
  },
  {
    titulo: '',
    id: '',
    imagen: '',
    fecha: ''
  },
  {
    titulo: '',
    id: '',
    imagen: '',
    fecha: ''
  },
  {
    titulo: '',
    id: '',
    imagen: '',
    fecha: ''
  }
]
```

Necesito ordenar el objeto con una función similar a esta:

```
this.articulos.sort( (a, b) => {
  return a.fecha < b.fecha;
});
```

Esto funciona mientras estoy en el servidor local de Angular, pero al compilar me da el error `error TS2339: Property 'sort' does not exist on type 'Object'.`

¿Cómo puedo hacer esto?

Comment: El método `sort` es de Array, y tu ejemplo es uno. Algo no cuadra, porque el error dice que no es un Array

Comment: puedes añadir mas código, como el tipo de dato de tu variable artículos,  tal vez el error esta en el tipo de dato con el que lo declaras

Answer (score 1):

Basado en [MDN Webdocs Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/sort) y una pregunta similar resuelta en [StackOverflow en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069666/sorting-javascript-object-by-property-value). Debes tener en cuenta lo siguiente, la función sort está disponible sólo para arreglos.

```js
// Declaramos arreglo de objetos
var arr = [ 
  {"id": 40},
  {"id": 1},
  {"id": 5},
  {"id": 200}
  ];
  
//Usamos la propiedad sort de los arreglos
arr.sort(function(a,b){
  return a.id - b.id;
});
//M{etodo alternativo con igual resultado
arr.sort((a,b)=>a.id-b.id);

/*Para ver los resultados en tu consola*/

console.log(arr.sort(function(a,b){
  return a.id - b.id;
}));

console.log(arr.sort((a,b)=>a.id-b.id));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```